# The product of derivative functions

Tags: calculus

> Let $f$ be a bounded derivative function, that is, $\exists\ F$, such that $F'=f$. Let $g\in C[a,b]$. Can we find $f(x)g(x)$ is also a derivative function, that is, $\exists\ H$, such that $H'(x)=f(x)g(x)$.

What I can guess is to use $\int fgdx=\int fd G=fG-\int f'G$. But $f'$ may not exists.

Comment: This is probably answered somewhere in: Richard John Fleissner, [*Multiplication and the fundamental theorem of calculus — a survey*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44151099), **Real Analysis Exchange** 2 #1 (1976), pp. 7−34. See also [papers that cite Fleissner's survey](https://www.google.com/search?q=Fleissner+%22multiplication+and+the+fundamental%22&filter=0).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro It sounds quite difficult.